# OSError: Label: File 'Gilroy-light.ttf' not found

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I m trying to add font file in my app but it is showing

```
OSError: Label: File 'Gilroy-light.ttf' not found
```

I have added `.ttf` at include ext. Line but then also this error is showing
Include ext. Line:

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf
```

Plz help me to solve this..

Comment: Where did you put your font? How did you load it? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: It is in the same location where main.py and spec file is. And it is showing :- OSError: Label: File 'Gilroy-light.ttf' not found. Btw I m using Google Colab

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of info to give a proper answer. But this is what I believe is going wrong.

The answer depends on whether you are executing your program on your system or on your android device. But since you have added a line from the buildozer.spec file I will assume you are either attempting to compile the program in buildozer and you are getting that error or you are getting this error when you are running the app on your phone.

In that case you need to copy the actual font file into your working directory(The directory in which your `main.py` file is. Also i would suggest that you only use one extension. Either use `.ttf` type or `.otf`